# Cordova build failed for ios after installing pushwoosh notifications plugin

Tags: ios, cordova, pushwoosh

We have done ios app using cordova.We used pushwoosh plugin to send push notifications.Recently we have updated pushwoosh plugin from version 3.6.5 to 6.2.2 (https://github.com/Pushwoosh/pushwoosh-phonegap-plugin). After installing new version we are not able to build project.

```
cordova plugin add pushwoosh-cordova-plugin@6.2.2
```

After installing

```
cordova build ios
```

We are getting below error

```
    The following build commands failed:
    CpResource www/plugins/com.pushwoosh.plugins.pushwoosh/www/PushNotification.js build/emulator/ITCPapyra.app/PushNotification.js
(1 failure)
Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/apple/ITCPapyra/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,ITCPapyra.xcodeproj,ARCHS=i386,-target,ITCPapyra,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,build,VALID_ARCHS=i386,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/apple/ITCPapyra/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/apple/ITCPapyra/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /Users/apple/ITCPapyra/platforms/ios/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: /Users/apple/ITCPapyra/platforms/ios/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:139:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:827:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
```

We are using cordova version 5.2.0, node version 4.4.7 .Please help how to solve this issue and build our project success.

Comment: Which Xcode version are you using to build ?

Comment: We are using Xcode 8.0

Answer (score 0):

```
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
```

Which environment do you use?